# $\chi^2$ is insignificant when Spearman's $\rho$ is significiant (and vice versa)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, spearman-rho

How can I interpret a situation where for two variables on an ordinal scale:

- $\chi^2$ test is not significant (p > 0.05) and Spearman's $\rho$ is significant
- $\chi^2$ test is not significant and Spearman's $\rho$ is insignificant

Dataset [labels are in Polish]:

- [SPSS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97551230ido22pd/PGSS_2010_zbior_danych.sav?dl=0)
- [txt [csv]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wemhlpsin640hnk/PGSS_2010_zbior_danych.csv?dl=0)

SPSS commends I used:

```
CRO q85a by q116
/CELLS COL
/STAT CHISQ.

NONPAR CORR
/VARIABLES=q116 q85a
/PRINT=SPEARMAN TWOTAIL NOSIG
/MISSING=PAIRWISE.
```

Comment: Have you seen both? Do you have an example?

Comment: Note that chi-square tests as usually understood will pay no attention to the order of categories.

Comment: @gung: I have dataset with two variables: one variable asks if inequality in Poland is too big and the second variable ask what respondent thinks about socialism. And p for X^2 is 0,407, but p for rho is ,002.

Comment: @Nick Cox: yeah, I see, but it's a bit strange for me

Comment: I can't comment without specific details. Can you show the data? Is this just a question of something like 5-point scales?

Comment: @NickCox: I edited my question with link to database. Yes, it is 5-point scales

Comment: That is no use to those of us who can't read .sav files, which I understand to be proprietary SPSS files. Very few active users here use SPSS. To be widely readable, post in a text format such as space, comma or tab-separated.

Comment: Sorry, now there is also link to txt

Comment: Can you give us the output, to save us running the file?

Comment: As I understand it frequencies in a 5 x 5 contingency table are enough to work with.

Comment: sure [question edited], but it's partialy in polish

Comment: Just post the contingency table w/ aggregate counts.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no surprise, as this are testing very different hypothesis. I get the following contingency table from your data (reading the .csv version)

```r
    -9   1   2   3   4   5   8
  1   5  22  63 320 117  83  57
  2   1   5  36 193  93  65  46
  3   0   2   7  35  13  15  11
  4   0   0   3  18  13  10   7
  5   0   0   1   6   1   2   2
  8   0   1   0   4   2   0   4
```

and this doesn't square with the description in the post. The `-9` might indicate missing, we don`t know. But using the data *as is*, my p-values are very different from the one in your post, and neither significant at conventional levels.

Anyhow, since your's are ordinal data, the Spearman correlation is the one you should use. The chisquare test does not use the ordinal information, and is inappropriate.

Comment: Re "inappropriate:" what is the hypothesis?  The question doesn't seem to say.